# Use modrewrite to pass URL variables to CSS file

Tags: mod-rewrite

Some of the html on one of my pages is styled with CSS in such a way that in order for it to be dynamic, the CSS code has to include a certain set of PHP variables. That being said, I edited my `.htaccess` file so that what is really a PHP file is tricked into being seen as a CSS file. The `.htaccess` file looks as such:

```
RewriteRule ^/css/bars/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*).css$ /css/bars.php?one=$1&two=$2&three=$3&four=$4 [L]
```

So, for in the head of the page, I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bars/0/0/15/2" />
```

But, the CSS file won't load. The file cannot be found on the server. Leaving me to believe that rewrite rule is incorrect. Any ideas?

Comment: To understand what the rewrite rule is trying to do, what's the complete URL for this segment path: `/css/bars/0/0/15/2`?

Comment: I'm sorry. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: `http://example.com/folder/folder/css/bars/0/0/15/2` is an example. What's the complete URL for the link in the question (`css/bars/0/0/15/2`)? That's important to understand what the rewrite rule is trying to match with the regex.

Comment: Ohhh. Locally, it's http://localhost:8888/css/bars/0/0/15/2

Comment: Next question. ¿What's wrong with your rule, what's the error you get and which of the strings in the URL are variable (`css`, `bars`, etc)?

Comment: I have no idea what the .htaccess rewrite error is. But, I know that it's incorrect because the link to the external style sheet in the page's head isn't linking to the CSS file.

Comment: Before I try to give any answer, why don't you try to see first what's going on. Temporarily replace [L] with [R=302,L] in the rewrite rule to display the substitution URL in the browser's address bar and copy-paste it into your question if possible.

Comment: Switched it and it didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !bars\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/css/bars/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? [NC]
RewriteRule .* css/bars.php?one=%1&two=%2&three=%3&four=%4 [L]
```

Maps silently

`http://example.com/css/bars/0/0/15/2`

With or without trailing slash. Always displayed in browser's address bar,

To:

`http://example.com/css/bars.php?one=0&two=0&three=15&four=2`

Strings `css`, `bars` and `bars.php` are assumed to be fixed, while `0/0/15/2` are all assumed to be variables and a quantity of 4.

The incoming URL structure has to be kept for the rule-set to work: First folder `/css` followed by `/bars` and so on.

For permanent redirect, replace `[L]` with `[R=301,L]`

Hope this is what you need.